# Swapping rows within the same pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, swap

I'm trying to swap the rows within the same DataFrame in pandas.

I've tried running

```
a = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2],[3,4]], index=range(2), columns = ['A', 'B'])
b, c = a.iloc[0], a.iloc[1]
a.iloc[0], a.iloc[1] = c, b
```

but I just end up with both the rows showing the values for the second row (3,4).

Even the variables b and c are now both assigned to 3 and 4 even though I did not assign them again. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a temporary varaible to store the value using `.copy()`, because you are changing the values while assigning them on chain i.e. Unless you use copy the data will be changed directly.

```
a = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2],[3,4]], index=range(2), columns = ['A', 'B'])
b, c = a.iloc[0], a.iloc[1]


temp = a.iloc[0].copy()
a.iloc[0] = c
a.iloc[1] = temp
```

Or you can directly use copy like

```
a = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2],[3,4]], index=range(2), columns = ['A', 'B'])
b, c = a.iloc[0].copy(), a.iloc[1].copy()
a.iloc[0],a.iloc[1] = c,b
```

Comment: Oh yes this solved the problem. Many thanks! I'm still unsure about when values are on a chain. Would you say that it would be safer to just always use the `.copy()` method when I am assigning new variables?

Comment: Yes by default they hold the reference to main object . Whatever changes  you do will reflect on main object. So u need copy.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer does not make changes the index name.

If you only want to alter the order of rows you should use `dataframe.reindex(arraylike)`. Notice that the index has changed.

[image]

Comment: Yes, using `.reindex()` is the one.

Answer (score 5):

In this way, it can be extrapolated to more complex situations:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2],[3,4]], index=range(2), columns = ['A', 'B'])
rows = a.index.to_list()
# Move the last row to the first index
rows = rows[-1:]+rows[:-1]
a=a.loc[rows]
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2],[4,5],[6,7]], index=['a','b','c'], columns = ['A', 'B'])
```

`df`

[image: Original DataFrame]

`df.reindex(['a','c','b'])`

[image]