# Swapping two rows (together with index) within the same pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a flat resale price [dataset](https://data.gov.sg/dataset/resale-flat-prices) (In case you are interested, I am using the Jan 2015 onward data).

First, I group the data by using 
`data.groupby('flat_type').sum()`, Then the data becomes:
[image]

### My attempt to swap rows

Now, I try to swap the last two rows by using the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890972/swapping-rows-within-the-same-pandas-dataframe):

```
b,c = data_by_type.iloc[-2], data_by_type.iloc[-1]
temp = data_by_type.iloc[-2].copy()
data_by_type.iloc[-2] = c
data_by_type.iloc[-1] = b
```

[image]

The content for the last two rows changed, but the index for the last two rows remains the same.

**So my question is:**
How to swap the entire row, including the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
df = df.iloc[np.r_[0:len(df) - 2, -1, -2]]
```

Alternative:

```
df = df.loc[df.index[:-2].tolist() + df.index[-1:].tolist() + df.index[-2:-1].tolist()]
```

---

```
print (df)
                  floor_area_sqm  lease_commence_date  remaining_lease  \
flat_type                                                                
1 ROOM                    1085.0                69125             1977   
2 ROOM                   40898.0              1788955            62356   
3 ROOM                 1430010.1             41448329          1344374   
4 ROOM                 3226160.4             67177320          2604002   
5 ROOM                 2349460.0             39663269          1555300   
MULTI-GENERATION          4105.0                49677             1708   
EXECUTIVE               943961.0             13059434           495628   

                  resale_price  
flat_type                       
1 ROOM            6.938000e+06  
2 ROOM            2.168112e+08  
3 ROOM            6.628663e+09  
4 ROOM            1.460442e+10  
5 ROOM            1.043298e+10  
MULTI-GENERATION  1.969189e+07  
EXECUTIVE         4.101716e+09
```