# Move row by name to desired location in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a df which looks like this:

```
         a   b
apple  | 7 | 2 |
google | 8 | 8 |
swatch | 6 | 6 |
merc   | 7 | 8 |
other  | 8 | 9 |
```

I want to select a given row say by name, say "apple" and move it to a new location, say -1 (second last row)

desired output

```
         a   b
google | 8 | 8 |
swatch | 6 | 6 |
merc   | 7 | 8 |
apple  | 7 | 2 |
other  | 8 | 9 |
```

Is there any functions available to achieve this?

Comment: this might help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890972/swapping-rows-within-the-same-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) for remove value and [`numpy.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) for add value to new index, last use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) or [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for change order of rows:

```
a = 'apple'

idx = np.insert(df.index.difference([a], sort=False), -1, a)
print (idx)
Index(['google', 'swatch', 'merc', 'apple', 'other'], dtype='object')

df = df.reindex(idx)
#alternative
#df = df.loc[idx]
print (df)
        a  b
google  8  8
swatch  6  6
merc    7  8
apple   7  2
other   8  9
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems good, I am using [`pd.Index.insert()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.insert.html) and [`pd.Index.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df.reindex(df.index.insert(-1,'apple').drop_duplicates(keep='last'))
```

---

```
        a  b       
google  8  8
swatch  6  6
merc    7  8
apple   7  2
other   8  9
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any built-in function, but one approach would be to manipulate the index only, then use the new index to re-order the DataFrame (assumes all index values are unique):

```
name = 'apple'
position = -1

new_index = [i for i in df.index if i != name]
new_index.insert(position, name)
df = df.loc[new_index]
```

Results:

```
        a  b
google  8  8
swatch  6  6
merc    7  8
apple   7  2
other   8  9
```